# How to mock axios call in test? Keep getting argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, axios, enzyme

How can I mock an axios call in my jest test? I am doing it like so

```js
jest.mock('axios');
const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;

test('something', () => {
...

  mockedAxios.get.mockReturnValueOnce({ data: [] });
});
```

I keep getting this error below:

> error TS2345: Argument of type '{ data: undefined[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig) => AxiosPromise'.
>         Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'data' does not exist in type '(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig) => AxiosPromise'.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Jasmine can you try this?

```
import axios from 'axios';
jest.mock('axios');

test('something', () => {
...
  const mockGet = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get');
  mockGet.mockResolvedValue({ data: [] });
});
```